# Google Area Chart is not taking value as int

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm using Google's [Area Chart](http://code.google.com/intl/no-NO/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/imageareachart.html) to dispaly a graph.

For some reason I'm not ble to use values past into the function:

I have the following code:

```
function SetAreaChartData(valueString) {

    //This works
    AreaChartData.setValue(0, 0, 'SomeName');
    AreaChartData.setValue(0, 1, 500);
    AreaChartData.setValue(0, 2, 500);
    AreaChartData.setValue(0, 3, 500);

    //This does not work

    // First I must "cast" the input to string in order to use the .split function
    var str = new String(valueString); 

    // Then I split the string in order to get an array of string
    val = str.split(",");

    AreaChartData.setValue(0, 0, 'SomeName');
    AreaChartData.setValue(0, 1, val[0]*1); //Multiply by one to cast it to integer
    AreaChartData.setValue(0, 2, val[1]*1);
    AreaChartData.setValue(0, 3, val[2]*1);
}
```

I've also tried using `parseInt(val[0])`, but that is not helping either.

Why won't `.setValue` recognize `val[0]` as an integer?